# css v-verticallayout, how to set height

Tags: java, html, css

I am using login form(in vaadin). I used CSS style to get the background color. The problem is that its not showing the effect to 100% of the page.

[image: Problem]

I did "inspect" on chrome and found that "v-verticallayout v-layout v-vertical v-widget v-has-width" has no height at element.style. If I add height to element.style to 100%( on the inspect tool of chrome), the effect can be seen to full page. How can I fix this in CSS 
[image: How it should be]

following is my CSS

```
.dmr{

    @include valo;

    background-image: url(sciome-vector-logo.png); 
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px 80px;

    /* Applies to every page */
    html {
        height:100%;
        margin-bottom:1px ;
        color:black;
    }

    body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .v-slot {
        overflow: hidden;
        height:100%;
    }



    .entire_div {
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
    }   


    .v-verticallayout-entire_content_div {
        text-align: center;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }

    .div{
        height: 100%;
    }

    .entire_content_div {
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }


    /* Main view properties */

    .v-slot-page_content_div {
        height: calc( 100% - 55px );
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .page_content_div {
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 80vh;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .v-slot-login {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have direct acces to the HTML file?

Comment: No. I am using vaadin. So I set the style to different components using CSS classes.

Comment: Ok, so you can't add any class to the HTML element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the CSS you've provided, none of those selectors are selecting the element you added `height: 100%;` to the `element.style` in the browser. Something like this might select it:

```
.v-verticallayout { 
     height: 100%;
}
```

I also noticed you have a `.div` selector in your CSS but I'm thinking you meant the selector `div`, not a class called div.

EDIT: 
Changed the selector suggested to be more specific so it doesn't override the other elements with the same classes that OP was running into issues with.

This on solution of many where you'd just trickle down till you get specific enough that it won't affect your other elements.

```
div.v-verticallayout.v-layout.v-vertical.v-widget.v-has-width {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In principle you're right, but you dont know wether the class you add the height is used somewhere else, where you dont need a height of 100%

Comment: I did try this. It solves my problem but it pushes the whole login box down to the page. I inspected the CSS and see that it created another attribute, but didnt add anything to element.style. I need something which can add to element.style.

Comment: All `element.style` is doing is adding to that specific element. In css, if you want to target just that element, then you have to be more specific with your selector. Something like `div.v-verticallayout.v-layout.v-vertical.v-widget.v-has-width` will be selecting only the element that has that combination of classes.